# Send multiple timestamp fields in influxdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, grafana, influxdb, influxdb-2

I want to send two dateTime field in influxdb using node js for each point, as I want to visualize a gantt chart in grafana dashboard eventually. I have tried sending a date object and the utc timestamp but still I am getting error bad timestamp even for sending one of the two fields. How can I send dateTime as a metric to influxdb in js and also send two time fields together for a single value? Also if there is another approach to generate a gantt chart it would be helpful too

I tried both, sending a date time object as timestamp and also sending timestamp but none of them worked, it shows bad timestamp.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.